# Python class inheritance/Logic gate & circuit example

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, python-3.x

I'm currently self-learning Python, and I'm reading 'Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures' (Brad Miller, David Ranum). I've stumbled upon the basic example of inheritance. Although I can see what it does, I need an explanation, *how* it works actually. The Code is as follows:

```
class LogicGate:

    def __init__(self,n):
        self.name = n
        self.output = None

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getOutput(self):
        self.output = self.performGateLogic()
        return self.output


class BinaryGate(LogicGate):

    def __init__(self,n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self,n)

        self.pinA = None
        self.pinB = None

    def getPinA(self):
        if self.pinA == None:
            return int(input("Enter Pin A input for gate "+self.getName()+"-->"))
        else:
            return self.pinA.getFrom().getOutput()

    def getPinB(self):
        if self.pinB == None:
            return int(input("Enter Pin B input for gate "+self.getName()+"-->"))
        else:
            return self.pinB.getFrom().getOutput()

    def setNextPin(self,source):
        if self.pinA == None:
            self.pinA = source
        else:
            if self.pinB == None:
                self.pinB = source
            else:
                print("Cannot Connect: NO EMPTY PINS on this gate")


class AndGate(BinaryGate):

    def __init__(self,n):
        BinaryGate.__init__(self,n)

    def performGateLogic(self):

        a = self.getPinA()
        b = self.getPinB()
        if a==1 and b==1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

class OrGate(BinaryGate):

    def __init__(self,n):
        BinaryGate.__init__(self,n)

    def performGateLogic(self):

        a = self.getPinA()
        b = self.getPinB()
        if a ==1 or b==1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

class UnaryGate(LogicGate):

    def __init__(self,n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self,n)

        self.pin = None

    def getPin(self):
        if self.pin == None:
            return int(input("Enter Pin input for gate "+self.getName()+"-->"))
        else:
            return self.pin.getFrom().getOutput()

    def setNextPin(self,source):
        if self.pin == None:
            self.pin = source
        else:
            print("Cannot Connect: NO EMPTY PINS on this gate")


class NotGate(UnaryGate):

    def __init__(self,n):
        UnaryGate.__init__(self,n)

    def performGateLogic(self):
        if self.getPin():
            return 0
        else:
            return 1


class Connector:

    def __init__(self, fgate, tgate):
        self.fromgate = fgate
        self.togate = tgate

        tgate.setNextPin(self)

    def getFrom(self):
        return self.fromgate

    def getTo(self):
        return self.togate


def main():
   g1 = AndGate("G1")
   g2 = AndGate("G2")
   g3 = OrGate("G3")
   g4 = NotGate("G4")
   c1 = Connector(g1,g3)
   c2 = Connector(g2,g3)
   c3 = Connector(g3,g4)
   print(g4.getOutput())

main()
```

I'm mostly doubted by the `tgate.setNextPin(self)` statement in `Connector` class `__init__`. Is it a method call? If it is, why is it called with just one parameter, when there are two actually required by the `setNexPin` function in `UnaryGate` and `BinaryGate` classes `(self, source)`? How does the `fromgate` variable ends up as the `source` arrgument? Does this statement 'initiliaze' anything actually, and what?

Next thing which troubles me is, for example, when I `print(type(g4))` before declaring `g4.getOutput()`, I get `<class '__main__.OrGate'>`, but when the `g4.getOutput()` starts, and functions start calling each other, to the point of calling `getPin` function, if I put `print (self.pinA)` before `return self.pinA.getFrom().getOutput()`, I get the `<__main__.Connector object at 0x2b387e2f74d0>`, although `self.Pin` is a variable from `g4` `OrGate` instance. How can one variable from one class instance can become object of another class, which isn't inheriting it? Does this have something with a work of `setNextPin()` function?

Can someone explain this to me as I am new to OOP and thorougly confused by this piece of code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, `tgate.setNextPin(self)` is a method call. `tgate` is an object, presumably an instance of one of the gate types. When you access `instance.method`, Python gives you a "bound method" object, which works pretty much like a function, but which puts the instance in as the first argument when it is actually called. So, `tgate.setNextPin(self)` is really calling `type(tgate).setNextPin(tgate, self)`

Your second question seems to reflect a misunderstanding of what attributes are. There's no requirement that an object's attributes be of its own type. In the various `LogicGate` sub-classes, the `pin`/`pinA`/`pinB` attributes are either going to be `None` (signaling that the user should be prompted for an input value) or an instance of a `Connector` (or something else with a `getFrom` method). Neither of those values is a `LogicGate` instance.

As for where the `Connector` instance you saw came from, its going to be one of the `c1` through `c3` values you created. `Connector` instances install themselves onto a pin of their `tgate` argument, with the `setNextPin call` you were asking about in your first question. I can't really speak to the `g4` gate you are looking at, as it seems to be different than the `g4` variable created in your example code's `main()` function (it is a different type), but I suspect that it is working as designed, and it's just a bit confusing. Try accessing the `pinX` attributes via `g4.pinA` rather than inspecting them inside of the methods and you may have a bit less confusion.

Here's a bit of code with outputs that should help you understand things a bit better:

```
# create a few gates
g1 = AndGate("G1")
g2 = OrGate("G2")

# at this point, no connectors have been hooked up, so all pinX attrs are None:
print("G1 pins:", g1.pinA, g1.pinB) # "None, None"
print("G2 pins:", g2.pinA, g2.pinB) # "None, None"

# test that the gates work independently of each other:
print("G1 output:", g1.getOutput()) # will prompt for two inputs, then print their AND
print("G2 output:", g2.getOutput()) # will prompt for two inputs, then print their OR

# create a connection between the gates
c1 = Connector(g1, g2) # connects output of g1 to first available pin (pinA) of g2

# we can see that g2.pinA has changed
print("G2 pins after connection:", g2.pinA, g2.pinB)
   # "<__main__.Connector object at SomeHexAddress>, None"

# now, if we get g2's output, it will automatically request g1's output via the Connector
print("G2 output:", g2.getOutput())
   # will prompt for 2 G1 inputs, and one G2 input and print (G1_A AND G1_B) OR G2_B
```

If you want to play around with these classes more, you might want to add a `__str__` (and/or `__repr__`) method to some or all of the classes. `__str__` is used by Python to convert an instance of the class into a string whenever necessary (such as when you pass it as an argument to `print` or `str.format`). Here's a quick `__str__` implementation for `Connector`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Connector between {} and {}".format(self.fgate.name, self.tgate.name)
```

Comment: When I visualize my code in the online visualizer, and when the `setNextPin` function is executed by creating Connector object `c1 = Connector(g1,g3)`, and calling `tgate.setNextPin(self)` and frame is created, `self` points to the `OrGate` (`g3`) object which is `tgate` parameter, and `source` points to the `fgate` Connector object. So, the passed `source` argument is not really `tgate` but rather `fgate`. I'm still doubted by that how the `fgate` argument gets passed in a `tgate.setNextPin(self) `statement`.

Comment: I don't think `source` comes from `fgate` (which is `g1`), but from `self` in the call made in `Connection.__init__`. Your call stack begins with `main()`, which is running the statement `c1 = Connection(g1, g3)`. Next is `Connection.__init__(<c1>, g1, g3)` which is running `tgate.setNextPin(self)` (I'm putting `c1` in angle brackets because it isn't bound to that name yet). That resolves to `BinaryGate.setNextPin(g3, <c1>)`, which is the top of the stack.

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://goo.gl/nSpm4g , it shows the code visualization a step after `tgate.setNextPin(self)` is executed, `setNextPin` function called, and the frame created. `self` points to the `togate` Connector instance or `G3` (`OrGate`) instance, and `source` points to the `fromgate` Connector instance, or `G1` (`AndGate`) instance. I'm still confused by this and would like you to have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @Reloader: I think you are misreading the visualization somehow. Everything I see there is as I would expect. In `setNextPin`, the `self` parameter has only one value, the `OrGate` with name attribute `G3`. Don't get confused by the `self` parameter in the previous frame, which is completely unrelated!

Comment: I see the blue arrow coming from the `setNextPin` frame, `self` argument (the right arrow), connecting with the arrow which comes from `togate` Connector instance, and they are connected in the place of `OrGate` `output` attribute.

Comment: @Reloader: Yes, `self` points at the `OrGate` instance and `source` points at the `Connector` instance. There's also a reference from the `Connector` instance to the `OrGate` instance in the `Connector`'s `togate` attribute (which was just set up a few steps before the point you linked to). Don't read too much into the location where the arrows land on the left side of the object; the references are to the whole object. I guess I don't understand what you're expecting to be different in this scenario.